# how can I debug Android application in device from computer?

Tags: android, debugging

my problem is how to debug existing applications in Android device for example Chrome, Google Play or Dropbox, etc. 
I have no idea what I have to do after turn on USB debugging. 
I have Android studio, but I only found some tips about creating and testing applications, but I want to debug existing, not new applications.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Do you have the source-code for the existing application?

Comment: all `release` builds have `debuggable=false` then only it can be uploaded on `playstore`. you cannot debug them. you need to create new app to debug which will have `debuggable=true` by default.

Comment: thanks a lot...my assignment was to join Android device via USB in debugging mode and try to find out something. But I don t know what information I can from debugging except of the applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `debuggable` flag in the AndroidManifest which specifies if the app can be debugged. Generally apps you get from the App Store will have that set to `false`.

Comment: thank you... do you know some applications from app stroe which can be debuggable ?